# Index for table in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I had a question on indexes.  I have a table like this:

```
id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
cust_id VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
dt DATE NOT NULL,
sale_type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
sale_type_sub VARCHAR(40),
amount DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL
```

The table has several million rows.  Assuming that queries will often filter results by date ranges, sale types, amounts above and below certain values, and that joins will occur on cust_id... what do you all think is the ideal index structure?

I wasn't sure if a clustered index would be best, or individual indexes on each column?  Both?

Comment: Side note: I would strongly recommend **not** to use `DOUBLE` for money values - it's not safe, it's susceptible to rounding error. Use `DECIMAL(p,s)` instead.

Comment: I agree, sorry, this was just a quick demo of the fields that I have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any serious table in SQL Server should always have a well-chosen, good clustering key - it makes so many things faster and more efficient. From you table structure, I'd use the `ID` as the clustering key.

Next, you say joins occur on `cust_id` - so I would put an index on `cust_id`. This speeds up joins in general and is a generally accepted recommendation.

Next, it really depends on your queries. Are they all using the same columns in their `WHERE` clauses? Or do you get queries that use `dt`, and others that use `sale_type` separately?

The point is: the fewer indices the better - so if ever possible, I'd try to find one compound index that covers all your needs. But if you have an index on three columns (e.g. on `(sale_type, dt, amount)`, then that index can be used for queries

- using all three columns in the `WHERE` clause
- using `sale_type` and `dt` in the `WHERE` clause
- using only `sale_type` in the `WHERE` clause

but it could **NOT** be used for queries that use `dt` or `amount` alone. A compound index always requires you to use the *n left-most columns* in the index definition - otherwise it cannot be used.

So my recommendation would be:

- define the clustering key on `ID`
- define a nonclustered index on `cust_id` for the JOINs
- examine your system to see what other queries you have - what criteria is being used for selection, how often do those queries execute? Don't over-optimize a query that's executed once a month - but do spend time on those that are executed dozens of times every hour.

Add one index at a time - let the system run for a bit - do you measure an improvement in query times? Does it *feel* faster? If so: leave that index. If not: drop it again. Iterate until you're happy with the overall system performance.

Comment: This is phenomenal, thank you so much.  I had read similar suggestions in various pieces of documentation, but this relates it to my real-world example and it totally makes sense.  THANK YOU!

Comment: @JeffreyKramer: you're welcome. Indexing in SQL Server isn't an exact science - it depends on a lot of factors, lots of experience and trial-and-error, too

Comment: Very explanatory answer! Additionally, you might consider partitioning this table. Also it might help to have the index stored on a different disk.

Answer (score -3):

The best way to find indexes for your table is sql server profiler.

Comment: This actually sounds like an absolutely terrible way to find indexes for your table.